# Can't access on the Scope Data

Tags: angularjs

I try to access to the variable `$scope.result` in my controller but the last output just says `undefined`. Inside the function the output is fine. Is there something wrong with my `$scope` (thought both use the same)?

```
 $scope.result = "";
 theMovieDb.find.getById({"id": "tt0993846", "external_source":"imdb_id"}, function successCallback(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data);
    $scope.result = data.movie_results[0].poster_path;
    console.log(data.movie_results[0].poster_path);
    }, function(error){});
 console.log($scope.result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call **$scope.$apply** like this:

```
$scope.result = "";
 theMovieDb.find.getById({"id": "tt0993846", "external_source":"imdb_id"}, function successCallback(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data);

    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.result = data.movie_results[0].poster_path;
    });

    console.log(data.movie_results[0].poster_path);
    }, function(error){});
 console.log($scope.result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I another problem, because in firebug send first the last console.log command before the one inside therefore the scope is still empty.

Comment: That's because it's an asynchronous call so of course the outer 'console.log()' will run before the one in the success callback.